# Access is Denied running Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am getting "access is denied" trying to run a Jupyter notebook on Windows 10, from a c:\jupyter subdirectory.

I have reinstalled Anaconda but using the corporate process for software installation, and I think my original installation may have been done manually using the software downloader.

The weird thing is, if I active a specific conda environment - then all of a sudden I am able to launch the notebook from that folder.

```
(base) C:\jupyter>jupyter notebook
Access is denied.

(base) C:\jupyter>activate ariel

(ariel) C:\jupyter>jupyter notebook
[I 15:11:13.191 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 15:11:13.191 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\ariel\share\jupyter\lab
[I 15:11:13.671 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\jupyter
[I 15:11:13.671 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:11:13.671 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=01701eceb8e6938d4983f553eb276a4e1ff69ea970824ea6
[I 15:11:13.671 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=01701eceb8e6938d4983f553eb276a4e1ff69ea970824ea6
[I 15:11:13.671 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 15:11:14.281 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/MP9293Q/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3548-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=01701eceb8e6938d4983f553eb276a4e1ff69ea970824ea6
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=01701eceb8e6938d4983f553eb276a4e1ff69ea970824ea6
```